# How can I write output from a Subprocess to a text widget in tkinter in realtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess

Hey I want to display the output from a subprocess into my GUI in a tk.Text Widget. I have a Code and it works minimal but it is not in realtime. How can I achieve that the output from the Terminal will be written to the Text widget in Realtime???

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import threading

#### classes ####

class Redirect():
    
    def __init__(self, widget, autoscroll=True):
        self.widget = widget
        self.autoscroll = autoscroll

    def write(self, textbox):
        self.widget.insert('end', textbox)
        if self.autoscroll:
            self.widget.see('end') # autoscroll

    def flush(self):
        pass

def run():
    threading.Thread(target=test).start()

def test():

    p = subprocess.Popen("python myprogram.py".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, text=True)
    while p.poll() is None:
        msg = p.stdout.readline().strip() # read a line from the process output
        if msg:
            print(msg)


##### Window Setting ####

fenster = tk.Tk()
fenster.title("My Program")


textbox = tk.Text(fenster)
textbox.grid()

    
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(fenster, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
scrollbar.grid()

textbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=textbox.yview)

start_button= tk.Button(fenster, text="Start", command=run),
start_button.grid()
    

old_stdout = sys.stdout    
sys.stdout = Redirect(textbox)


fenster.mainloop()

sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

Comment: You need to use `"python -u myprogram.py"` instead of `"python myprogram.py"`.

Comment: @acw1668 Your anser wored too thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stack overflow. I modified your code a bit (you had a `,` after defining `start_button` and didnt import `sys`, also i put your code below `##### Window Setting ####` into a boilerplate-code).

Your main issue was, that you do not make your `Text` widget available in your `run` and furthermore in your `test` function (executed as a thread). So i handed over your widget as an argument to both functions (probably not the most pythonic way, however). For executing a command bound to a button i used `from functools import partial` and binded the command including an argument via `command=partial(run, textbox)`. Then i simply handed over the argument in `run` to the thread with `args=[textbox]` in the line where you create & start the thread. Finally, i updated the textbox with `textbox.insert(tk.END, msg + "\n")` in your `test` function while removing the `print()`. The insert appends any text at the end to the textbox, the `"\n"` starts a new line.

Here is the (slightly restructured) complete code (**app.py**):

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import threading
import sys
from functools import partial


# ### classes ####

class Redirect:
    
    def __init__(self, widget, autoscroll=True):
        self.widget = widget
        self.autoscroll = autoscroll

    def write(self, textbox):
        self.widget.insert('end', textbox)
        if self.autoscroll:
            self.widget.see('end') # autoscroll

    def flush(self):
        pass


def run(textbox=None):
    threading.Thread(target=test, args=[textbox]).start()


def test(textbox=None):

    p = subprocess.Popen("python myprogram.py".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, text=True)
    while p.poll() is None:
        msg = p.stdout.readline().strip()  # read a line from the process output
        if msg:
            textbox.insert(tk.END, msg + "\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fenster = tk.Tk()
    fenster.title("My Program")
    textbox = tk.Text(fenster)
    textbox.grid()
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(fenster, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    scrollbar.grid()

    textbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=textbox.yview)

    start_button = tk.Button(fenster, text="Start", command=partial(run, textbox))
    start_button.grid()

    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = Redirect(textbox)

    fenster.mainloop()
    sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

And here is the code of the test-file **myprogram.py** i created:

```
import time

for i in range(10):
    print(f"TEST{i}")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Do you speak german? 
Your option is a very good one thank you! Mainly because I then have the option to press other buttons. But I have an exit button in my real GUI which I can use because of you. If I press the script "myprogram.py" continues to run. Is there a way to end the script? Maybe via a terminal kill..

Comment: @JMO_44 i do speak german - glad i could help :) You can kill a process started with `subprocess.Popen` by the process id. Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/12892026) for more details.